# Using Dynamic CEFSharp with ChromeTabs but AddressChanged is not exposed

Tags: wpf, dynamic, tabs, cefsharp

I am making an app that started with the CEFSharp minimal example code and I am using ChromeTabs in Wpf. I have my CEFSharp diverting popup windows into tabs correctly but I am having an issue grabbing the URL of these dynamic CEFSharp windows. For some reason AddressChanged is not exposed for these dynamic windows. I have tried to make use of LoadingStateChanged to place the URL in a textbox but that creates all new issues with the threads. I have spent the past few days trying to get this to work and it is driving me crazy. This is how my new tab is created but it does not expose AddressChanged event.

```
int counttabs = tbControlRCI.Items.Count-1;

            string popURL;
            popURL = popup_request;
                tbControlRCI = this.etTabCntrlRCI;
            //here we should open a new tab and place a new rcibrowser in it and give it the url
            RCIBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(popURL);
                RCIBrowser.Name = "RCIBrow_" + counttabs;

                string shorturl = popURL.Substring(popURL.LastIndexOf("/"), popURL.Length - popURL.LastIndexOf("/"));
                ChromeTabs.ChromeTabItem newTabItem = new ChromeTabs.ChromeTabItem
                {
                    Header = shorturl,
                Name = "RCITab_" + counttabs,
                Content = RCIBrowser

            };
                LifespanHandler lifeRCI = new LifespanHandler();
                RCIBrowser.LifeSpanHandler = lifeRCI;
                lifeRCI.popup_request += life_popup_request;

                tbControlRCI.Items.Add(newTabItem);
                tbControlRCI.SelectedIndex = tbControlRCI.Items.Count - 1;
```

My XAML only has a ChromeTabsControl that I place all of these dynamic Tabs and Browsers into.
Can anyone show the error of my ways?

EDIT: 
Ok, thanks amaitland, I have tried a few different ways to do that and it just does not update for some reason. All I need is a textbox to show the address the Browser is on, so one way is fine. So I tried this:

```
Binding b = new Binding();
b.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
b.Path = new PropertyPath("Address");
b.ElementName = "RCIBrowser";

txtbxRCI.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, b);
```

Thanks a bunch,
Hometownnerd

Comment: There is no AddressChanged event in WPF,  you can bind directly to the Address property. You can bind in code.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for helping, I edited my question and added what I tried, but it does not show the address either on start or when url changes..Again appreciate your help.

Comment: ElementName should be the instance name of the ChromiumWebBrowser. The unique name of the object

Comment: Alternatively you can implement http://cefsharp.github.io/api/79.1.x/html/T_CefSharp_IDisplayHandler.htm and assign your instance to http://cefsharp.github.io/api/79.1.x/html/P_CefSharp_Wpf_ChromiumWebBrowser_DisplayHandler.htm

Comment: Ok, I see why that did not work since I used the control not the name, but after I fixed it, it still did not show the URL. So then I created a class that does the displayhandler, I think I built it correctly since I do get the event fire in the class but when I set the Action URLAddressRCI(chromiumWebBrowser.Address); it complains about the threads and not owning it and I seem to not have the ability to use the dispatcher.invoke like I do in the MainWindow. How can I get around that? Sorry to be so dense.

Comment: You can cast IWebBrowser to ChromiumWebBrowser and access the dispatcher, you should use BeginInvoke instead of invoke.

Comment: OMG I finally got it to work, I just needed to reference the addressChangedArgs.Address in the OnAddressChanged event in the class, it did not complain about threads and it was available to me to pass back. Now to get this to work for all of the tabs that get created. Thank you so much for your help and getting me straightened out, keeps getting harder and harder to learn how to do this new stuff. Thank you again!!

Comment: Binding is likely easier,  once you get the values correctly. Using xaml really is the preferred approach. Looks like the chrometabs source has some examples of this https://github.com/sskodje/wpfchrometabs-mvvm/blob/master/Demo/MainWindow.xaml#L34

Comment: Yeah, but I am creating tabs dynamically when my browser gets a popup, so I need to bind in code behind after the browser is created  so I am trying to have an address bar on each tab to show each user where they are, for troubleshooting issues.

Comment: You can do that with xaml/databinding, it would be much nicer/cleaner. Anyway, do whatever works for you.